# Companion rescue quest bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

On the first rescue mission I had, which involves saving a Whiterun stall clerk from some forsworn at a camp/dungeon, I went there and cleared all the enemies (even from the within the dungeon) but the character isn't there.

Also when inside the Whiterun walls the quest indicator is shown as it being in the same location even the quest is outside the walls.

Even though when I got there the indicator was like this and she wasn't there I still cleared it out and got part of the quest complete for doing so but it's still telling me to talk to the non-existent person.

I can not progress further in the companions till it is done. It's almost like the game wants me to jump over the bloody walls of Witerun.

Any idea how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I could think of (other than starting the quest over from an earlier save) is utilizing the "Clairvoyance" spell. This should produce a glowing trail that will allow you to track down said individual. If that doesn't work then you are stuck with the backtrack to an earlier save option, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this issue a couple of times from different characters, the way in which I have normally sorted this issue is to simply use the wait function for a period of time, normally around 10-12 hours and then the character should spawn into the game as what I could tell when I had this issue was that the NPC didn't actually spawn in the dungeon to begin with.

The other way with dealing with this if you cannot find the NPC and you are sure that they have actually spawned into the dungeon would be to use a spell to detect life like the other people have suggested.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with other people in Whiterun. When I completed what I thought I had to do, I returned to the place and the person wasn't there, although the marker was. It took me about 15 minutes of searching in various houses around the place to locate the person I needed to talk to, and even then there was no marker.

My best solution for you is to search around everywhere in the cave or wherever the person is supposed to be. That includes on the floor and even maybe trapped in a hanging cage. The marker probably just hadn't updated to them yet.

Comment: A Detect Life spell will do wonders for locating an NPC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I figured out the solution is to actually jump over the wall.

In Whiterun there's a barrel that you have to jump on, and then jump over the wall. Check on youtube on how to do it but after that, you just run through a barren skyrim until you get to the marker and they'll follow you.

After that, you fast travel to where they need to go and you can complete your quest.

Comment: "Check on youtube" is rarely a quality answer to a question.  If you know of a video, consider linking to it.